# How to craft a dynamic file address from text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The result of this is what a legit address looks like in a link between files:

```
="'"&CELL("filename",A1)&"'!$B$3"
```

(you can paste this as a result add a `=` in front of it and it will work just fine)

Except concatenate or indirect don't want to accept it.
If you want to see the real thing -  make two files, copy a cell from one - paste link to the other and close the source file.

Is there any way to trick it to use the text as a path?

I do it this way - because I can always determine where the other files are based on where the current file is. So any redirects are a simple matter of substituting text.

I'm trying to avoid VBA atm.

Funny enough it will work for address crafting for within the file:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#'"&RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1),LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1),1))&"'!","A5"),"FFS")
```

(with this, click on the cell result text to jump to A5)

Comment: You can't close the source file.............because `INDIRECT()` is volatile.

Comment: Doesn't matter for now, I can't make the full address work from text. I can only craft internal addresses from text. If i use the address it self directly it don't need to go through indirect or anything else.